# mysql query using values (no subselect)

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relationship

Due to the permanent use of ORM I have no idea how to write this query, but I need to write it without ORM.

tables design:

users:

> |id|username|...

ports:

> |id|user_id|port|

My app gets a username, now I need to find all ports for the matching username using the id of the user to get the ports.

Comment: `JOIN` the two tables.

Comment: But how to save the user_id which I need to have before I use JOINS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `JOIN` to find the ports for the user specified by userparam (or whatever you call it.):

```
select u.id, u.username, p.id, p.user_id, p.port
from users u
  join ports p on u.id = p.user_id
where u.username = :userparam
```

(You can remove the columns you don't need from the `SELECT` list.)

Answer (score 1):

```
users:
    id|username|...

ports:
    id|user_id|port|
```

think about the `SELECT` line last. just put a place holder to begin

```
select count(*)
```

then actually begin. ask what tables do I need to get data `FROM`?

```
FROM users, ports
```

this is going to (conceptually) make a new table with rows that have every user matched up with every port.
how do I filter out all of the data in this new table that does not
apply to my query? ignore everything except `WHERE` you tell it to match

```
WHERE user.id == ports.user_id
```

you can think of this is as filtering for rows in the giant table made from all the rows of all the tables you put in the `FROM` clause.

Now that you have these rows of everything you can `SELECT` which columns  from the new table you made that you are interested in.

lets say you want any port.id (s) returned.

```
SELECT port.id
FROM users, ports
WHERE user.id == ports.user_id
```

A nicer syntax that keeps the `WHERE` parts near their `FROM` parts
which gets important when you have lots of tables looks like this

```
SELECT port.id
FROM users join ports ON user.id == ports.user_id
```